# How do you select a graphics driver on a headless box?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, headless

I am setting up an EC2 GPU instance for experimenting with CUDA programming using an Ubuntu 14.04 AMI.  I installed the nvidia drivers indicated by the major version on the Nvidia download page for the Grid K520 (340) from the xorg-edgers PPA.

`ubuntu-drivers devices` shows that this is the recommended version.  However, `lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12` has no "Kernel driver in use" section.  Articles I've looked at suggest using the GUI to select the driver, but as I'm ssh'ing into a headless box there's no GUI.

I am trying doing X forwarding to my local box, but I can't figure out how to start the software properties dialog from the command line.  Just selecting the driver from the command line (a la jockey-text) would be the best, though.

Answer (score 2):

OK, after installing a bunch of X stuff (`apt-get install xubuntu-desktop xfce4 -y`), I was able to run `software-properties-gtk` and foward it over the X connection.  It showed that the proprietary driver actually was already in use.

If anyone knows an easier way to tell which driver is in use, I'd appreciate that.